# query failed on Msql Database Update

Tags: mysql, sql, apache

*Hi I am always getting error Query Failed but i didn't get error on apache2 log

I want to change account password without login in on website.

Hope someone could help me resolve this problem.

//Sanitize the POST values

```
$login = clean($_POST['login']);

$email = clean($_POST['email']);

$newpw = clean($_POST['newpass']);

$cnewpw = clean($_POST['cnewpass']);





//Input Validations

if($login == '') {

    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Login ID missing';

    $errflag = true;

}

if($email == '') {

    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Email missing';

    $errflag = true;

}

if($newpw == '') {

    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';

    $errflag = true;

}

if($cnewpw == '') {

    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Confirm password missing';

    $errflag = true;

}

if( strcmp($newpw, $cnewpw) != 0 ) {

    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Passwords do not match';

    $errflag = true;

}
```

//Check for duplicate login ID

```
if($login != '' && $email != '') {

    $qry = "SELECT * FROM t_account WHERE name='$login' AND email='$email'";

    $result = mysql_query($qry);

    if($result) {

        if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {

            $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username and or Email is not in our system!';

            $errflag = true;

        }

        @mysql_free_result($result);

    } else {

        die("Query Failed");

    }





//Create update query

$qry = "UPDATE t_account SET (pwd, pw2) VALUES('".md5($_POST['newpass'])."','$newpw')";

$result = @mysql_query($qry);



//Check whether the query was successful or not

if($result) {

    header("location: register-success.html");

    exit();

}else {

    die("mysql_error");

}

}
```

?>

*

Answer (score 0):

You can change password via phpMyadmin. Check the password generator code. It must be md5 I guess.

Answer (score 0):

After you enter the if try to print the value of the $qry string, copy paste IT on tour SQL client and see what you get

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL Syntax for your Update-String is incorrect (at least in ANSI-SQL).

It is

```
INSERT INTO table (col1,col2) VALUES...
```

or

```
UPDATE table set col1=val1, col2=val2 WHERE...
```